# show subfolder modified date with specific string

Tags: powershell

in Windows 2008 R2, I have a shared folder structure like this

```
D:\USERS

D:\USERS\USER1
D:\USERS\USER1\AUTOBACKUP
D:\USERS\USER1\DROP
D:\USERS\USER1\EXHIBIT

D:\USERS\USER2
D:\USERS\USER2\AUTOBACKUP
D:\USERS\USER2\DROP
D:\USERS\USER2\EXHIBIT
```

There are are 100 users folders and all users copy there important data in there  **AUTOBACKUP** folder. Every **AUTOBACKUP** folder have several sub folders and files in it.

My requirements is to display ONLY the **AUTOBACKUP** folders name who are not updated in last 1 month, means no file in written in any autobackup or in its subfolders. (I dont requires drop/exhibit folders details as it can be updated by any1 , but autobackup can be updated only by the corresponding user)

Result Something like:

```
D:\USERS\USER1\AUTOBACKUP - Updated
D:\USERS\USER2\AUTOBACKUP - ALERT: Not updated since last month ...
```

or show me result only for users whose auto backup have not updated from past month.

I tried to get result by powershell commands, but it shows me results if some one update the drop/exhibit too, and i want to exclude them in search criteria, the search should be done only in autobackup.

**UPDATED:**
Ok I am trying following script, but getting hit by long path error. the folders are deep, means autobackup folders have several sub folders inside it with long file names too, therefore getting error. howto overcome this issue now :(

```
$users = Get-Content C:\myusers.txt   
$lastMonth = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1)
$backupfiles = Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse
$logLocation = "D:\mylog.log"
foreach ($user in $users){
    $path = "D:\Users\$user\AUTOBACKUP"
    $backupfiles = Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse
    foreach ($file in $backupfiles){
        $modifiedDate = $file.LastWriteTime
        if ($modifiedDate -ge $lastMonth){
            $nobackup = $false
            break
            } else {
            $nobackup = $true
            }
        }
        if ($nobackup){
            Add-Content -Path $logLocation -Value "$filepath  -  NOBACKUP"
        }
    }
```

Comment: @
getting error using
`Get-ChildItem -Path \\?\d:` OR `Get-ChildItem -Path \\?\d:\temp`  OR `Get-ChildItem -Path \\?\d:` OR  "\\?\$path"

Comment: Hmm, get-childitem doesn't support it. Use IO class: `$backupfiles = ([IO.DirectoryInfo]"\\?\$path").GetFiles('*', [IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories)`

Comment: @wOxxOm
Ok I accept, my skills are way  too limited. IO_CLASS with full command line syntax, its over my head :) , in the meanwhile i will keep trying the traditional methods ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem 'D:\USERS' -Directory | ForEach-Object {

    $RecentAutoBackupFiles = @(
        Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\USERS\$($_.Name)\AUTOBACKUP" -File -Recurse | 
            Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -ge [datetime]::Now.AddMonths(-1) }
        )

    if (0 -eq $RecentAutoBackupFiles.Count)
    {
        "$($_.Name) - ALERT no files in AUTOBACKUP since 1 month ago"
    }
}
```

Untested...

Comment: getting below error 

`PS D:\> .\test.ps1
Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Direct
ory'.
At D:\test.ps1:1 char:36
+ Get-ChildItem 'D:\USERS' -Directory <<<<  | ForEach-Object {
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterB
   indingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comm
   ands.GetChildItemCommand`

Comment: Oh, you're using PowerShell v2.0, that's going to have to be `Get-ChildItem 'D:\USERS' | Where { $_.PsIsContainer } | ` Although, I see you have long path problems and this script won't do anything about that.

Comment: Ok this worked.
many thanks for time n efforts . appreciate it :)
now just banging my head on howto overcome the long path issue :) kinda stucked with it...

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
Get-ChildItem D:\Users -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ? { $_.IsContainer -and $_.Name -eq "AUTOBACKUP" } | Select fullname,@{Name="Status";Expression={if ($_.lastwritetime -lt ((Get-Date).AddMonths(-1))) { "Updated" } else { "ALERT: not updated since $($_.lastwritetime)" } }}
```

This should get every sub-object of D:\Users, then filter directories only with "AUTOBACKUP" name, and finally displays the full path + name of the filtered directories and a conditional string based on the Last Write Time of the folder

Comment: Is that a good test, getting the LastWriteTime of the AUTOBACKUP folder itself? It appears to update if a file is created inside the folder, but not if a file is created inside subfolders...?

Comment: the command should every folder/subfolder/files inside the auto backup folder, if it found no file updated (not written since last month) then it should alert. i guess this is ok ?

Comment: @Luca Clavarino , getting this error, long path error 

`Get-ChildItem : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully
qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name mu
st be less than 248 characters.
At line:1 char:14
 `

Comment: Ok I am trying an script (updated in first post), but getting hit by long path error. the folders are deep, means autobackup folders have several sub folders inside it with long file names too, therefore getting error. howto overcome this issue now :(

Comment: You could skip the path too long errors by adding `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` as parameter of Get-ChildItem

Comment: OK I have executed this ... but the users folder used space is 1.8 TB in total, so there are LOT of files/folders in it. this may take a moment :)

Comment: Getting error after script ends.

`
Get-ChildItem : Cannot bind parameter 'ErrorAction'. Cannot convert value "SilentlyContinue⌂" to type "System.Managemen
t.Automation.ActionPreference" due to invalid enumeration values. Specify one of the following enumeration values and t
ry again. The possible enumeration values are "SilentlyContinue, Stop, Continue, Inquire".
At D:\test.ps1:9 char:61
+     $backupfiles = Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -ErrorAction <<<<  SilentlyContinue⌂
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
` & no result come

Comment: You have a wrong character in "SilentlyContinue". I've edited the command in the answer.